# how to instal leveldb in ubuntu 14.04 Lts

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to instal LevelDb using [this](http://techoverflow.net/blog/2012/12/14/compiling-installing-leveldb-on-linux/) and [this](https://gist.github.com/dustismo/6203329) link both gives error when i type `make` in console

```
g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-soname -Wl,libleveldb.so.1 -I. -I./include -fno-builtin-memcmp -pthread -DOS_LINUX -DLEVELDB_PLATFORM_POSIX -O2 -DNDEBUG        -fPIC db/builder.cc db/c.cc db/dbformat.cc db/db_impl.cc db/db_iter.cc db/filename.cc db/log_reader.cc db/log_writer.cc db/memtable.cc db/repair.cc db/table_cache.cc db/version_edit.cc db/version_set.cc db/write_batch.cc table/block_builder.cc table/block.cc table/filter_block.cc table/format.cc table/iterator.cc table/merger.cc table/table_builder.cc table/table.cc table/two_level_iterator.cc util/arena.cc util/bloom.cc util/cache.cc util/coding.cc util/comparator.cc util/crc32c.cc util/env.cc util/env_posix.cc util/filter_policy.cc util/hash.cc util/histogram.cc util/logging.cc util/options.cc util/status.cc  port/port_posix.cc -o libleveldb.so.1.17 
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [libleveldb.so.1.17] Error 127
```

and after that no command works as given in the links please help me how can i instal leveldb in ubuntu

edit suggested by @A.B
here is the output of `apt-cache policy g++`

```
g++:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
  Version table:
     4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy g++`

Comment: i have edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to get the compiler, therefore install with:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

or better:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Answer (score 1):

1. clone the repo

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/google/leveldb.git
   ```
2. change into directory

   ```
   cd leveldb/
   ```
3. build the damn thing

   ```
   make
   ```
4. copy generated libs etc to `local/lib`

   ```
   sudo scp out-static/lib* out-shared/lib* /usr/local/lib/
   ```
5. change into include dir

   ```
   cd include/
   ```
6. copy stuff recursively again

   ```
   sudo scp -r leveldb /usr/local/include/
   ```
7. create the necessary links and cache (for use by the run-time linker

   ```
   sudo ldconfig
   ```
8. s...tuff should work now, rejoice :)

Comment: Can you explain what these commands do?  just posting commands doesn't qualify for an answer here, as lot of the users are new users

Comment: have you ever used StackOverflow before ? These commands do qualify as answer and they all translate to specific instructions e.g. cd means change directory , git clone means clone a repo scp means secure copy etc, those looking for an answer will know what they mean.

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low quality answer, and instead of choosing to delete, I tried to comment. This answer does serve a purpose as it is. I just think if you could edit it in a way that New comers could also understand, then it would be better. no need to be rude, we all want what's best for the site :)

Comment: There. All better now.